# How to make lookup between two collections when an item in an array exists in the other collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In Lookup with a pipeline, I would like to get the linked records from an array in the parent document.

```
// Orders
[{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5b91a25c68de2538620689"), 
    "Name" : "Test", 
    "Products" : [
        ObjectId("5b5b919a5c68de2538620688"), 
        ObjectId("5b5b925a5c68de2538621a15")
    ]
}]

// Products
[
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5b5b919a5c68de2538620688"),
   "ProductName": "P1"
},
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5b5b925a5c68de2538621a15"),
   "ProductName": "P2"
}
,
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5b5b925a5c68de2538621a55"),
   "ProductName": "P3"
}
]
```

How to make a lookup between Orders and Products when `Products` field is an **array**!

I tried this query

```
db.getCollection("Orders").
    aggregate(
    [
    {
     $lookup:
         {
           from: "Products",
           let: { localId: "$_id" , prods: "$Products" },
           pipeline: [
              {
                "$match": 
                {
                    "_id" : { $in: "$$prods"  }
                }
              }, 

              { 
                $project: 
                { 
                  "_id": "$_id", 
                  "name": "$prods" ,
                }
               }
           ],
           as: "linkedData"
         }

    },
    {
        "$skip": 0
    },
    {
        "$limit": 1
    },
    ]
)
```

This is not working because `$in` is expecting an array, and even though `$$prods` is an array, it is not accepting it.

Is my whole approach correct? How to make this magic join ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were going in the right direction the only thing you missed here is to use [**`expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) with [**`in`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) aggregation operator which matches the same fields of the document

```
db.getCollection("Orders").aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Products",
    "let": { "localId": "$_id" , "prods": "$Products" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$prods" ] } } },
      { "$project": { "_id": 1, "name": "$ProductName" } }
    ],
    "as": "linkedData"
  }},
  { "$skip": 0 },
  { "$limit": 1 }
])
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: Yes, this is what I was missing!! Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

You just need regular [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), the documentation states that:

> If your localField is an array, you may want to add an $unwind stage to your pipeline. Otherwise, the equality condition between the localField and foreignField is foreignField: { $in: [ localField.elem1, localField.elem2, ... ] }.

So for below aggregation:

```
db.Orders.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from :"Products",
            localField: "Products",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "Products"
        }
    }
])
```

you'll get following result for your sample data:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5b91a25c68de2538620689"),
        "Name" : "Test",
        "Products" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5b919a5c68de2538620688"),
                        "ProductName" : "P1"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5b5b925a5c68de2538621a15"),
                        "ProductName" : "P2"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works but I could not make the right projection in the aggregation when I want to show few fields only from the nested collection. When I tried so, it was showing each field in the nested collection as an array, instead of an array of objects. So I moved the projection to the lookup pipeline

Comment: I see, you can try with $map as a fallback for MongoDB < 3.6 but if you don't need that then `$lookup` + `pipeline` is okay

Answer (score 0):

have you try unwind before the lookup. use unwind to brak the array annd then make lookup.

Comment: Unwind would break the array I want to keep in the result

Comment: Yes you need to group the data after the looup
in sequence  -- unwind--> lookup-->group.